# How should I query these tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

That's the database I have:

[image: E-R]

This is the (first) Offer-table with articles and the respective ID:

[image: offer]

This is the (second) Bid-Table with the offered articles:

[image: bid]

I have to query the numbers of the articles that have offered the same number of

So I want to spend this here:

```
ID1  ID2 Number_of_Orders                      
  1    2                2                
  1    5                2                 
  2    5                2
```

I tried to join it into inline views:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(SELECT BID.ID as ID1 FROM OFFER 
    INNER JOIN BID ON OFFER.ID=BID.ID
    GROUP BY GEBOT.ID) v1,
(SELECT BID.ID as ID2 FROM OFFER 
    INNER JOIN BID ON OFFER.ID=BID.ID
    GROUP BY BID.ID) v2, 
(SELECT COUNT(GID) as NUMBER_OF_ORDERS FROM BID
INNER JOIN OFFER ON OFFER.ID=BID.ID
    GROUP BY BID.ID
    ) v3;
```

but I do not know how I should spend the two IDs under the condition that they have the same number of orders (bids)

Comment: [Please post text instead of images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) whenever you can, and describe anything that has to be an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to count the bids for each ID, and then do a self-join on that result to find matches:

```
with cte (id, number_of_bids) as (
  select id, count(*)
  from bid
  group by id
)
select c1.id as id1, c2.id as id2, c1.number_of_bids
from cte c1
join cte c2
on c2.number_of_bids = c1.number_of_bids
and c2.id > c1.id
order by id1, id2;

       ID1        ID2 NUMBER_OF_BIDS
---------- ---------- --------------
         1          2              2
         1          5              2
         2          5              2
```

The CTE just gets the number of offers for each ID with simple aggregation. (You could do it with inline views instead of a CTE, but you'd be counting them twice, once in each inline view).

Then the main query joins that CTE to itself on the aggregated `number_of_bids` being equal, and also one the second ID being higher than the first - which eliminates duplicates. Without doing that you'd see a row where ID1 was 5 and ID2 was 2, i.e. the reverse of the last of the three rows you want (and the same for the other two), plus each ID/count matched with itself.

You don't need to join to the offer table - you aren't using anything data from that.

Answer (score 0):

you simply join(inner join) these two tables and put the condition such as table1.bidPrice = table2.bidPrice

Comment: select * from OFFER f join BID b on f.GID = b.GID where f.bidPrice = b.bidPrice

Comment: Sry , I accidentally inserted the same table twice. Have changed it

Comment: So then the query will be :  select * from OFFER f join BID b on f.ID= b.ID where f.id IN (  SELECT b.ID
    FROM BID b
GROUP BY b.BIDPrice
  HAVING COUNT(b.BIDPrice) > 1)  Hope that helps

Comment: @S.H Please edit your post if you want to improve it instead of commenting.

Comment: you mean add as an answer instead of comments

Comment: At select b.id i get an "not a Group By expression" error

Comment: @S.H - don't add another answer; click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47838246/edit) for this one, and put your suggested query into your answer (as formatted text). I'm not sure you're calculating the right thing though - the question seems to be about the number of bids, not the prices?